# How to use other payment gateway in Laravel cashier?

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on Saas based application where I am using Laravel cashier. By default, Laravel cashier is using stripe. I want to use Razorpay instead of the stripe. Is it possible to achieve this in Laravel cashier? If Yes, Please let me know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use Laravel Cashier with [stripe](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/billing) or [paddle](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/cashier-paddle).
Currently, cashier does not support razorpay.

You can [install the razorpay package here](https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-php). Also, here is some guides on how to implement payment systems with razorpay:

https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-razorpay-payment-gateway-exampleexample.html

https://www.w3adda.com/blog/laravel-5-8-razorpay-payment-gateway-integration

Comment: Can you give examples for recurring payments using Razorpay?

Comment: Is it not possible to get RazorPay in Laravel Spark ?